# How to obtain Azure credentials using kubectl?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I have a following `kubectl` command to obtain the credentials for my Azure cluster:

```
kubectl config set-credentials token --token="$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" --auth-provider=azure
```

However, this throws the following error:

```
creating a new azure token source for device code authentication: client-id is empty
```

After doing some investigation, I found out that we need to supply additional information for `client id`, `tenant id`, and `apiserver id`:

```
kubectl config \
  set-credentials "<username>" \
  --auth-provider=azure \
  --auth-provider-arg=environment=AzurePublicCloud \
  --auth-provider-arg=client-id=<kubectl-app-id> \
  --auth-provider-arg=tenant-id=<tenant-id> \
  --auth-provider-arg=apiserver-id=<apiserver-app-id>
```

How should we obtain the `client id`, `tenant id`, and `apiserver id` details?

Comment: hello @jtee, may i know if you have referred this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-cluster?tabs=azure-cli#connect-to-cluster-using-kubectl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `kubectl config set-credentials` is used to [set credentials](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#define-clusters-users-and-contexts) as the name implies. If you want to get some information from your cluster you have several ways to do. For example you can use Azure Portal. Everything is described [in this article](https://www.inkoop.io/blog/how-to-get-azure-api-credentials/). For example to get Tenant ID you need to:

> 1. [Login into your azure account](https://portal.azure.com/).
> 2. Select azure active directory in the left sidebar.
> 3. Click properties.
> 4. Copy the directory ID.

To get Client ID:

> 1. [Login into your azure account](https://portal.azure.com/).
> 2. Select azure active directory in the left sidebar.
> 3. Click Enterprise applications.
> 4. Click All applications.
> 5. Select the application which you have created.
> 6. Click Properties.
> 7. Copy the Application ID .

To get Client Secret:

> 1. [Login into your azure account](https://portal.azure.com/).
> 2. Select azure active directory in the left sidebar.
> 3. Click App registrations.
> 4. Select the application which you have created.
> 5. Click on All settings.
> 6. Click on Keys.
> 7. Type Key description and select the Duration.
> 8. Click save.
> 9. Copy and store the key value. You won't be able to retrieve it after you leave this page.

You can also find these informations using cli based on [oficial documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/credential?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_credential_list).

You can also find additional example for  [Tenant ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-to-find-tenant) (example with Azure portal and cli options):

```
az login
az account list
az account tenant list
```